# What are 'cascading rules'?

Tags: css

What are cascading rules? what do they mean? All I know is the following:

In ascending order according to importance (low to high):

1. User agent declarations
2. User normal declarations
3. Author normal declarations
4. Author important declarations
5. User important declarations

Are these the rules of CSS?

Comment: http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/css/structure.html

Comment: see the [W3CSchools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) documentation

Comment: @hexblot [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) is NOT the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/).

Comment: @ajp15243: Stupid mistake, fixed.

Comment: @hexblot It's still WRONG

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: It basically means that stylesheets can reference each other stylesheets in a cascading fashion and styles that appear in later style sheets will overwrite styles appearing in earlier stylesheets...

Answer (score 0):

[The specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order) is clear on defining the cascade.  What you include in your question is only the *importance* of stylesheet rules.  Rules within a particular stylesheet also have specificity within a stylesheet.  For rulesets with the same specificity, order is what matters.

For example, within a single author stylesheet:

```
.link { color: red; }
.link:hover { color: green; }
.also-link { color: blue; }
```

For an element with class `link`, it will have the `color: red` rule.  If you hover over it, it will have `color: green`.  If an element has class `link also-link`, it will be `color: blue` because the `.also-link` rules are declared *after* `.link` and the specificity is the same.  If you hover over `link also-link`, it will be `color: green` because `.link:hover` has higher specificity even though it is declared earlier in the stylesheet.